# Service Mileage and its effects

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, service

I own a Mercedes Benz CLA 200.

The service interval is shown as 15K, how much can you stretch this without a problem?

Comment: What year is your MB?

Answer (score 1):

Service schedules are ***recommended*** intervals to keep your car in optimal running condition. This does not mean if you go beyond it that there will automatically be damage.

How far you can "stretch it" without a problem depends on your car, how you are driving it, what conditions you drive in, and if you are current on having it serviced. If you put a lot of miles(km) on the car each year, it becomes more important to maintain it properly.

If you are already late for recommended servicing, have it completed as soon as you can. If the expense of the servicing is the issue, ask the mechanic what is the most important part to accomplish first.

Of course, if you never have it serviced you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Mercedes use a '[flexible service system](http://www.benzshops.com/mercedes-flexible-service-system)' where the car warns you when it's time for service. The service interval depends on your driving style and the environment where your drive (the amount of pollution, the quality of the fuel etc.). This would allow you to safely stretch the interval.

On some cars, the service interval can be switched from fixed interval to flexible interval.